# JQuery POST is corrupting URL

Tags: jquery, post

I have a restful service, can test with Postman and it works. But when I use JQuery $.post it fails. The server logs the incoming request and it is quite different from that is logged from the Postman request.

**Postman** request gets logged like this (all is well):
[26/Jul/2015:11:58:27 -0500] "POST /api/customers/1001/users HTTP/1.1" 200 1

**JQuery** request gets logged like this (fails):
[26/Jul/2015:12:03:19 -0500] "POST /customer/%5Bobject%20Object%5D HTTP/1.1" 404 1045

Javascript code. I have tried many permutations of the URL, it doesn't seem to matter what I use, it seems to ignore it completely:

```
var url = 'http://mywebsite.ca/api/customers/1001/users';

$.post({
 url: url,
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: 'text',
 data: xml
}).done(function() {
 alert('success!');
}).error(function() {
 alert('error occurred');
});
```

I have tried many formats of the post; like with 'content', with dataType of xml, etc. Always get the same server error, the URL is all messed up.

```
XML looks like this:
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' +
'<ns2:ca.zzz.bus.schemas.Api.xsd xmlns:ns2="uri">' +
'    <email>newcustomer@newcustomer.com</email>' +
'    <customerId>1001</customerId>' +
'    <password>newuserpass</password>' +
'</ns2:ca.avox.bus.schemas.avoxApi.xsd>';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you making this request from same domain and port as api? if not would be a CORS issue

Comment: yes same server; have tried relative URLs as well, it seems like the url: parameter is ignored entirely.

Comment: what is the `xml` object being sent? Not defined in your code. What do you mean by `url param ignored`? It's a post request, won't be any url params. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab to see exactly what is sent, returned etc

Comment: Oooooo... I see it... I was thinking xml was being returned.. you are sending xml. BUT...you have no key/value pair being sent...just a value. How are you trying to receive this in your php?

Answer (score 0):

No help from the jquery documentation, but somebody else had a working solution here on SO.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml' 
    },
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': url,
    'data': xml,
    'content': xml,
    'dataType': 'xml',
    'success': alert(1),
    'error': alert(2),
    });
```

Another problem (fixed), the server was returning text when I expecting xml. Yes I'd prefer JSON, but some people (server guy) are set in their ways.